# How to reverse key=>value order of a nested array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, nested, flip

so the array looks like this:

```html
$folderIDs = array(
 "FolderID"=>0,
 "FolderName"=>"Main Folder",
 "Folders"=>array(
  array(
   "FolderID"=>23,
   "FolderName"=>"First SubFolder",
   "Folders"=>array()
  ),
  array(
   "FolderID"=>4,
   "FolderName"=>"Second SubFolder",
   "Folders"=>array(
    array(
     "FolderID"=>99,
     "FolderName"=>"SecondSub SubFolder ",
     "Folders"=>array(
      array(
       "FolderID"=>27,
       "FolderName"=>"SecondSubSub SubFolder",
       "Folders"=>array()
      )
     )
    )
   )
  ),
  array(
   "FolderID"=>46,
   "FolderName"=>"Third SubFolder",
   "Folders"=>array()
  )
 )
);
```

And the array could be "more" nested as subsubsub folders could also have subfolders and so on.

What we would want to a reconstructed array that looks like this:

```html
$reconstructed_folderIDs = array(
 0 => array(
  "FolderName" => "Main Folder",
  "ParentFolder" => "",
 ),
 23 => array(
  "FolderName" => "First SubFolder",
  "ParentFolder" => 0,
 ),
 4 => array(
  "FolderName" => "Second SubFolder",
  "ParentFolder" => 0,
 ),
 99 => array(
  "FolderName" => "SecondSub SubFolder",
  "ParentFolder" => 4,
 ),
 127 => array(
  "FolderName" => "SecondSubSub SubFolder",
  "ParentFolder" => 99,
 ),
 46 => array(
  "FolderName" => "Third SubFolder",
  "ParentFolder" => 0,
 ),
);
```

Are there quick or possible solution into this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a rather nasty way to obtain the results you require, quick but dirty.

```
function process(&$result, $record, $parent = NULL) {

  $f_id = $record['FolderID'];
  $f_name = $record['FolderName'];
  $f_data = $record['Folders'];

  if (!isset($result[$f_id])) 
      $result[$f_id] = [];  

  $result[$f_id]['FolderName'] = $f_name;
  $result[$f_id]['ParentFolder'] = $parent;

  if (empty($f_data)===FALSE)
      foreach( $f_data as $useless => $folder_record )      
          process($result, $folder_record, $f_id);      
}

$reconstructed_folderIDs = [];
process($reconstructed_folderIDs, $folderIDs );
```

Comment: Thank you! And I don't think it's dirty nor is there a better solution (I guess?) -- for me, it's perfect. :)

I see that the "solution" is actually running the same function within the function itself if the subfolder array is not empty. Many thanks, Majin! :)

Comment: Yup.  This is called a "recursive function".  Best wishes.